Angular 17 | ng build --configuration production converting special characters to unicode
We successfully upgraded our Angular application from version 11 to version 17, tested the functionality, and took a dev build. However, we are currently using the command ng build --configuration production to take production builds, and we are encountering the following problems. Any advice or assistance would be much valued.
We are using the below method to validate the inputs and remove the special characters
escapeRegExp(value: string): string {
    return value.replace(/[{}\(\)\^$&%#!@=<>:;,~`'\’\*\"\?\/\+\|\[\\\\]|\]/g, '');
}

Now the problem is, while building the application in production mode with the below configuration, ’ is getting relaced as \u2019. That means the above method is converted as below in the minified main.js file
escapeRegExp(o){return o.replace(/[{}\(\)\^$&%#!@=<>:;,~`'\\u2019\*\"\?\/\+\|\[\\\\]|\]/g,"")}

Below is the configuration we are using for production build.
"configurations": {
  "production": {
     "optimization": true,
     "outputHashing": "none",
     "sourceMap": false,
     "namedChunks": false,
     "extractLicenses": true,
     "vendorChunk": false,
     "buildOptimizer": true,
  }
}


Does ’ really need to be escaped? Maybe this is not the solution you were looking for, but my guess is that removing the escape, it will work. Indeed /\u2019/.test('’') is true

And since you are inside square brackets, I guess that no char (except ]) needs to be escaped
